# Convert String of type "2015-23-07T00:00:00Z" to XMLGregorianCalender of format "07/23/2015T00:00:00Z"

Tags: java, date, datetime, calendar, gregorian-calendar

I am calling a Web Service which accepts date as Xmlgregoriancalendar of format `"07/23/2015T00:00:00Z"` but what I have currently from my database is `"2015-23-07T00:00:00Z"`.

How to convert this String type of `XMLGregorianCalender` of type

```
"MM/dd/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
```

Since that service is hosted by some third party I can't change the schema and need to implement this conversion.

I tried this

```
Date d = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");                                                       
String formattedDate1 = sdf1.format(d);                                                  
Date date = sdf1.parse(formattedDate1);                                                
GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar;
XMLGregorianCalendar result = null;
gregorianCalendar = (GregorianCalendar)GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
gregorianCalendar.setTime(date);
result = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gregorianCalendar);
```

Comment: Are you actually storing it as a string in your database? If so, why? I wouldn't expect XMLGregorianCalendar to use a format of "MM/dd/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", as that's not the standardised format in XML... The web service you're calling is pretty broken, by the sounds of it. I suspect you'll need to use SimpleDateFormat instead.

Comment: No Actually I am taking date from my DB.  Any idea how can I convert it to XMLGreogorianCalender.

Comment: you want to convert from `2015-23-07T00:00:00Z` to `07/23/2015T00:00:00Z`?

Comment: yes, a String to XmlgreogorianCalender with format 07/23/2015T00:00:00Z

Comment: But with `MM/dd/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'` = `07/23/2015T00:00:00.000Z` not `07/23/2015T00:00:00Z`.

Comment: actually it will work with it and without it. But the problem is not this. Problem is XmlgreogorianCalender is not accepting this format. Any idea how to implement this ?

Comment: " XmlgreogorianCalender with format 07/23/2015T00:00:00Z" is non-sensical, because that's not the XML format of a date/time. As I said before, you'll need to use SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: Jon exactly it seems non sensical, but that's what third party service (which I am calling) requests accept. I used simple date format to convert my date into that format but when I parse the same in XmlgregorianCalender it outputs something else

Comment: As I see it, you can't use XMLGregorianCalendar for such non-standard format. You need to create the XML yourself and represent the datetimes as strings when constructing it.

Answer (score 1):

```
java.text.DateFormat outputFormat =new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
java.text.DateFormat outputFormat1 =new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-MM'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
System.out.println(outputFormat.format(outputFormat1.parse("2015-23-07T00:00:00Z")));//07/23/2015T00:00:00Z
```

Comment: it returns a string, I need XMLGregorianCalendar

Comment: @Anuj: Why? What makes you use XMLGregorianCalendar, which is basically the wrong choice when you don't want the XML standard way of representing a date/time?

Comment: @Jon I am calling a third party service. Now that service has a request schema. One parameter of that schema is lets say date of type XMLGregorianCalendar which only and only accepts datetime of type "MM/dd/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'". So this is the only reason I need to implement this. I know there are a lot other ways one can do but the problem is that third party service is not unchangeable

Comment: @Anuj: That's a non sequitur. Just because you're calling a third party service doesn't mean you need to use XMLGregorianCalendar, and given that the service doesn't accept the format that XMLGregorianCalendar uses, that suggests you *can't* use XMLGregorianCalendar. I don't know how many more ways we can explain that to you.

Comment: @Jon Thanks anyway for your feedback, I wish I could have shown you the actual request schema and while testing through soap UI it accepts the format which I just showed.

Answer (score 0):

You can using `SimpleDateFormat` to do this.

Grab the string from database, find and replace "-" with "\" then parse String to Date. Actually, `SimpleDateFormat` would accept `"MM-dd-yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"` type as well as `"MM/dd/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"` and you can do some calculation on it.